# How to validate array of objects using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating react form and validating form fields, 
If the field is empty error message shown below and state is set in errors.

I need to check the select field also, the select field is an array of objects. How to check the select option was empty or not?

check the example code 
https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-flower-2u1xw

Comment: Just a recommendation, you should take a look at [`formik`](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik)

Comment: you want to check if at least one option as been selection within the select field?

Comment: You need to initially assume the form is valid, then set the variable to false if an error is found: https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-resonance-msq12

Answer (score 1):

You already save the selected options into your state. So within your `validate` function, you just have to access the state and check the required properties. Also make sure you stay consistent with your variable names. Within your `validate` function, you name your return value `formIsValid` but later when you call the function, you use the return value as `errors` which is confusing. I renamed `formIsValid` to `hasErrors` to stay consistent.

```
  validate() {
    let required = ["name", "description"];
    let errors = {};
    let hasErrors = false;
    let data = this.state.data;

    required.forEach(w => {
      if (!data[w]) {
        hasErrors = true;
        errors[w] = "Please fill the required fields";
      }
    });
    this.setState({ errors: errors });

    // check if at least one option has been selected
    let currentLength = data.roles.length;
    if (!length) {
       hasErrors = true;
       erros["roles"] = "Please fill the required fields";
    }

    return formIsValid;
  }
```

And just add a error span as you did before:

```
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Roles</label>
          <Select
            isMulti
            value={this.state.roles}
            options={options}
            onChange={e => this.handleAccessChange(e)}
          />
          <span>{this.state.errors["roles"]}</span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is no logic for validating roles.

So something like the following is needed:

```js
  validate() {
    let required = ["name", "description"];
    let errors = {};
    let formIsValid = false;
    let data = this.state.data;

    required.forEach(w => {
      if (!data[w]) {
        formIsValid = true;
        errors[w] = "Please fill the required fields";
      }
    });

    if (this.state.roles.length === 0) {
        formIsValid = false;
        errors["roles"] = "Please select at least one role";
    }

    this.setState({ errors: errors });
    return formIsValid;
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-yalow-udgq7